# What does setWidth("*") do in CSS / SmartGWT?

Tags: css, gwt, smartgwt

I've come across some legacy code which uses SmartGWT. I suspect the API is present in standard GWT too.

```
widget.setWidth("*");
```

Keeping in mind that the same bit of code has:

```
otherWidget.setWidth100();
```

I'm not aware that CSS has anything like:

```
width: *;
```

So... is this code legitimate and if so what does it do... or not?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know... `auto`, perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SmartGWT `.setWidth("*")` means take up the **rest** of the available width. For example, if you have a `HPanel` with two children and one of the children has `setWidth("10%")` then implicitly the child with `setWidth("*"`) will have 90% width. This allows you to change the width of one child without having to update the other `setWidth` call.

Comment: It's perfectly llustrated by the showcase: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_layout one can see the two fixed percentage column and the rest when resizing the window

Answer (score 2):

Consider that you have a `Panel` with two children. Now if you set `setWidth("*")` for both child then the first child will take the required width and the second child will get whatever is left.

If you set `setWidth("60%")` for the first child and `setWidth("*")` for the second child then first child will take 60% of the width of the Panel and the second child will get the remaining 40%.

`.setWidth100();` and `.setHeight100();` these 2 make the component fill the canvas it is in. This mean set width & height 100% which is equivalent to `setWidth("100%")` and `setHeight("100%")` respectively.

This is basically used when you don't specifically want to set the widths of the child panel's. You specify a rough width of the first child panel and the width of the second child is automatically set.