# auto width canvas smartgwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

**how to set dynamic width in smartgwt?
i've tried this:

```
mainWindowBody = new VLayout();
mainWindowBody.setAutoWidth();
```

and it didn't work :S
can any one help?**

Comment: you don't know what is the GWT or smartGWT?

Comment: @MohdSabri Sorry, I haven't used it. I was reviewing first posts and saw this Java-like code.

Comment: emmm , you r right :)

Comment: @orique you should look into GWT. You'll be impressed by what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

Almost a year late to the party I know, but if this helps someone else it's worth it.  SmartGWT has a small oddity with respect to auto width - you must combine it with setOverflow(Overflow.VISIBLE) for it to work.  Put setAutoWidth and the overflow together on the same Layout/Canvas and it will size to its own width.

Comment: It's customary to leave some example code to make your answer, easier to understand. :) welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Canvas.setWidth(String)](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setWidth%28java.lang.String%29) with proper String or [Canvas.setWidth100()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setWidth100%28%29).

```
mainWindowBody.setWidth("*");
```

OR

```
mainWindowBody.setWidth100();
```

OR

```
mainWindowBody.setWidth("100%");
```

All will have same effect in this scenario.
That will cause `mainWindowBody` to expand and retract based on the size of available space.

There are three `setWidth()` (and setHeight) methods in Canvas:
`setWidth(int)` -  to set specific width in pixels - `setWidth(200)`
`setWidth(String)` - to use with percentages - `setWidth("50%")`
`setWidth100()` - a convenient method to set width to 100%

Check [What does setWidth("*") do in CSS / SmartGWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662237/what-does-setwidth-do-in-css-smartgwt) to see the difference between `setWidth("*")` and `setWidth100()`.

Comment: this will take the parent's width and height !
i want it automaticly decide the width and height of the widget.
thanks :)

Comment: @Moh'dSabri Based on what?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 canvas likes its size in pixels, and clears its content if you set a new size. But it has a `context.scale()` function that will keep the contents of the canvas when resized.

If you are trying to re-size the canvas when the user re-sizes the browser window, you can add a window re-size handler: `Window.addResizeHandler()`. I only know how to do this with GWT, not SmartGWT. When a window resize event is fired, use event.getHeight() and event.getWidth(), along with some math to compute a new pixel size for your canvas.

Comment: I work with html 4 , and i don't want to resize the window of browser,
thanks :)

Comment: You should use `setWidth(java.lang.String)`. You can try `setWidth("auto");` 
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setWidth(java.lang.String) 

Also, Canvas is a HTML5 feature.